# Multivariable Limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,-2)} \frac{x^4-y^4}{x+y}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How would I go about finding the multivariable limit to:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,-2)} \frac{x^4-y^4}{x+y}$$

The answer should be 32, but I'm not even sure how to start the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: use that $$x^4-y^4=(x-y)(x+y)(x^2+y^2)$$